Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment and error originates from a subprocess not pip
(Env) PS C:\Users\USER> pip install tflite-support
Collecting tflite-support
Using cached tflite-support-0.1.0a1.tar.gz (390 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [1 lines of output]
ERROR: Can not execute setup.py since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
how to be successful in install tflite-support

Just do what it says and manually install setuptools with pip, i.e. pip install -U setuptools in your virtual environment.
